# How to keep both keys after join with a named "by" in R

Tags: r, dplyr

With the dplyr join functions, you can use a named `by` if the join variables have different names. But the documentation warns "Note that only the key from the LHS is kept". How can I keep both keys?

eg

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(name= c("Ann", "Betsy", "Charlie", "Dave"), 
  dob= c(as.Date("2000-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
        as.Date("2001-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
    as.Date("2002-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2003-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")),
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(name= c("Ann", "Charlie", "Elmer", "Fred"), 
      date_birth= c(as.Date("2000-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
        as.Date("2004-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
        as.Date("2001-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
as.Date("2006-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Joining:

```
 inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name","dob" = "date_birth"))

     #  name    dob
     #  Ann     2000-01-01
```

How do I keep the dob and date_birth columns?

Comment: You are joining on them so they are the same. You can duplicate the column after the join if you want two copies of it: `... %>% mutate(date_birth = dob)`.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I'm filtering and joining multiple dataframes into a final dataframe and need to keep the columns consistent for bind_rows. I've been using mutate, but it makes it harder to roll my code into functions. I was hoping there'd be an easier way that acted more consistently to not drop columns.

Comment: Looking through the documentation, doesn't seem like `dplyr::inner_join`, `base::merge`, or `data.table::merge` offer this option. Presumably, if you're able to program the join  you could also program the mutate to duplicate the column.

Comment: You could use `sqldf`, e.g., `library(sqldf); sqldf("select * from df1 inner join df2 on df1.name = df2.name and df1.dob = df2.date_birth")`---that will keep the `dob` and the `date_birth` columns, but it will also give you two copies of the `name` column, `name` and `name..3`. You could then programmatically drop columns afterwards that have `..` in their names, `... %>% select(-matches("\\.\\."))`. But I think you would also find it difficult to program with as you'd need to construct the SQL queries as strings.

Comment: Or solve the problem later in your workflow: Use `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `rbind` so that missing columns will be filled in with `NA`, and do a final `coalesce` to fill in missing values as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the joining variables by using the argument `keep = TRUE`:

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name","dob" = "date_birth"), keep = TRUE)

  name.x        dob name.y date_birth
1    Ann 2000-01-01    Ann 2000-01-01
```

In this case, that also leaves you with the other joining variable, and because it has the same name in both sets of data, the variable "name" from the first data set (df1) becomes "name.x", and that from the second data set (df2) becomes "name.y". (Note that you can choose your own suffix, for instance, by using the argument `suffix = c("_df1", "_df2")`.)

Here, you would need some extra code to get rid of that duplicate variable:

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name","dob" = "date_birth"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  rename(name = name.x) %>% select(-name.y)

  name        dob date_birth
1  Ann 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
```

That's a bit silly though; as [Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor-thomas) points out in the comments for the OP, because you use inner_join, the joining variables necessarily have the same content. So the easiest solution is:

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name","dob" = "date_birth")) %>%
   mutate(date_birth = dob)
  name        dob date_birth
1  Ann 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
```